# Notice: Undefined index: file in php image up script

Tags: php, html, image

I have read a lot of different questions regarding this issue of undefined index when uploading image. But i have yet been able to fix the issue.

My problem is in the first time $_FILES["file"]["name"] being referenced. So i am thinking it is something to do between HTML upload image part and php. As in the image isnt even going from html to the php.

Thanks for your time

php code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

 $userid=$_SESSION['id'];
 $country = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['country']));

if (!$country)
    die ("Please fill out all fields"); 
    else 
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
$supported_image = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png');


$path = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if ((!in_array($ext, $supported_image) )&&($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 1000000))
```

etc

In the line  `for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++)`  which is the first time the image appeared in the php, it gives the undefined Index error.

HTML image code.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitform" class="form-horizontal" action='http://test.info/Bootstraptest/submitlisting.php' method='POST'  >


    <div class="control-group">
        <span class="btn btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" />
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
        <div class="controls">

        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100px;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified name attribute to input file element so it will not get in posted value cause it's not sending to server. try to change

```
<input type="file" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: I added the name in but its still the same, i think i had it before as well, i tried with name="file" name="file[]" and without all gives this same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="file" />` has no `name` attribute and is therefore not sent to the server.

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: I added the name in but its still the same, i think i had it before as well, i tried with name="file"  name="file[]" and without all gives this same error